# How to tell ansible to use different user for different environment?

Tags: amazon-ec2, vagrant, ansible

I'm building a machine on ec2 using Ansible. But I also have vagrant to test the script locally.

Here's my playbook

```
- name: Provision ec2
  hosts: all
  user: vagrant
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    gsutil_user_home: "vagrant"
```

If I want to use this playbook for EC2 I have to change the `user` and `gsutil_user_home` to be `ubuntu` to get it to work. Is there anyway I can make that as a variable and tell Ansible which user it needs to run based on some argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these values are generally consistent for the duration of your playbooks, you'd usually set them as group/host vars in inventory, and have different inventories or groups for different environments. But if you really want to do it with vars and pass them in with `-e`, that's fine too:

```
- name: Provision ec2
  hosts: all
  user: {{ my_ec2_user }}
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    gsutil_user_home: {{ gsutil_user_home }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to create folders say `develop`, `production`, `staging`. Set `hosts` files, `group_vars`, `hosts_vars` in there with correct variables and use them.

For example:

#### Folder structure

```
.
├── develop
│   └── hosts
├── production
│   └── hosts
├── test.yml
```

#### test.yml

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - debug: var=ansible_ssh_user
```

#### hosts - develop

```
[localhost]
127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_user=vagrant
```

#### hosts - dproduction

```
[localhost]
127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_user=ec2-user
```

### Run it:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i develop/ test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************** 

TASK: [debug var=ansible_ssh_user] ******************************************** 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "var": {
        "ansible_ssh_user": "vagrant"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
127.0.0.1                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   

$ ansible-playbook -i production/ test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************** 

TASK: [debug var=ansible_ssh_user] ******************************************** 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "var": {
        "ansible_ssh_user": "ec2-user"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
127.0.0.1                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```